# HTTP Connection in Iphone

Tags: iphone

Since I'm new in iphone I need help in learning about http Connections in Iphone. 
Please guide me to some tutorials so that I could learn some http connections tricks in iphone and could communicate with websites.

Also please guide me through some Sample code for the following problem:
I want to send some "Hello world" text to the site and got a reply back from the Web the same word with adiition of s i.e. "Hello World**s**".. please brothers guide me through any sample code.. it's a part of my application that I'm developing in iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i too new ,but i have sent  some msg(soap xml) via http request .my sample code is...

// get host address
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xyz.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// find msg length, here x is my msg 
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [x length]];

// specify  type of msg which u have to send to the host(mine is xml)
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
// name space which optional one
[theRequest addValue: @"http://mpack.h.org" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//type of http method
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// msg which is need to send to server
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// establish connection to host 
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSLog(@"Connecting....");

}
else
{
NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");

}

}

// delegate method for NSURLConnection
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction %@",error);
    [connection release];
    [webData release];

}
// u ll get response here
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

}

Answer (score 1):

You may check this. ASIHTTPRequest package is a highly recommended tool for handling traffic on a iPhone app.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 1):

The best resource is the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) from Apple. [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) section contains a number of sample codes.